# Deactivate second tab in Angular md-tabs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, tabs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Is there any attribute in angular material md-tabs that disables a tab something similar to what they have in Bootstrap.

```
$scope.tabs = [{
    title: 'Dynamic Title 1',
    content: 'Dynamic content 1'
}, {
    title: 'Dynamic Title 2',
    content: 'Dynamic content 2',
    disabled: true
}];
```

Something like this?

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
    <md-card-content id="nvd3-scrollable-content" style="height: 350px;"> 
                 <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom md-selected="selectedTab">
                      <md-tab ng-repeat="data in trendData" label="{{data.name}}">
                        <md-content class="md-padding" >
                         <div ng-if="data.name == 'FirstTab'">
                            <!-- some code-->
                        </div>

                         <div ng-if="data.name == 'SecondTab'">
                        <!-- some other code-->
                         </div>
                    </md-content>
                </md-tab>

            </md-tabs>
         </md-card-content>                      
    </div>
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xEJqGL here is the example to disable the tab

Answer (score 0):

In angular material there is one attribute 'md-selected' , you can use it by set md-selected="selectedTabIndex", let me show you:

```
<md-tabs md-selected="selectedTabIndex" md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom md-center-tabs="true" md-stretch-tabs='always'>
            <md-tab label="all" md-on-select="changeTab()">
                <md-content class="md-padding" flex>
                    <attendance-listing-content></attendance-listing-content>

                </md-content>
            </md-tab>
            <md-tab label="present" md-on-select="changeTab()">
                <md-content class="md-padding">
                    <attendance-listing-content></attendance-listing-content>
                </md-content>
            </md-tab>
            <md-tab label="absent" md-on-select="changeTab()">
                <md-content class="md-padding">
                    <attendance-listing-content></attendance-listing-content>
                </md-content>
            </md-tab>
        </md-tabs>
```

And then from your controller you need to just define **$scope.selectedTabIndex = '1';**, so then in that case first tab will be show or active, and same for others.

Comment: @blaa : You just need to provide index value, which tab you want to show, near md-selected="selectedTab" like i.e md-selected="2" (0,1,2,3)

Comment: Now, You need to just define a variable from controller $scope.selectedIndex = 1; that's it.

Comment: @blaa : Your code was just fine, just now you need to provide a selectedindex variable from controller

Comment: I want not to just select the second tab, I also want to disable it, to not be able to select it before just after I ahve clicked on something from the first tab .

Comment: <md-card-content id="nvd3-scrollable-content" style="height: 350px;"> 
            <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom md-selected="selectedIndex">
                <md-tab ng-repeat="data in trendData" label="{{data.name}}">
                    <md-content class="md-padding" > <div ng-if="data.name == 'FirstTab'">
                        </div> <div ng-if="data.name == 'SecondTab'"> 
                        </div>
                    </md-content> </md-tab> </md-tabs>
        </md-card-content>

Comment: something like in this example: codepen.io/anon/pen/xEJqGL. To disable the second tab

Comment: you can initialy set null, and then whenever you want to show it, you need to just re initialize it .

Comment: @blaa: There are a lot of option ng-if, ng-hide like this kind of other directives, you can do utilize it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-disabled` directive

Here is an example from Angularjs Docs

https://plnkr.co/edit/hOljQTwH5mSyUivEaipY?p=preview

Comment: If you're going to disable the second tab, do something like that
`<div ng-if="data.name == 'SecondTab' ng-disabled="data.disabled" ">`